# Visual Studio Code and pylint not finding module issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

First, I may have more of an issue with correct environment selection. I did a fresh install of Linux Mint 19 and apt dist-upgrade... etc... and then used apt-get and pip to install pymysql, pil.intertk and pylint for both python and python3 from the cli...

All is good from cli:

```
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5

~$ pylint3 --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint3 1.8.3, 
astroid 1.6.0
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0]

python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymysql
>>> import PIL
>>>
```

After installing VSC.... the only two selection of python environments are  2.7.12 and 3.5.2 ?

I then modified VSC settings with: `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"`

Which still shows as Python 3.5.2 64-bit within VSC

But here comes my issue that I have tried many suggestions I have found from searching with no luck...

pylint is not finding any module I install. I assume its due to the mix match of version ? But not sure how to resolve that?

When I try to specify the pylint path : `"python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/bin/pylint3"`

I get an invalid path error in VSC.. but its a valid path

```
~$ which pylint3
/usr/bin/pylint3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

So after some frustrating trail and error I have fixed the issue by uninstalling the Flatpak version of Visual Studio Code listed in the Linux Mint's Software Center... and installing the deb package from the official site.

After installing the deb package... the proper version of python are showing and pylint is working correctly.